# Undoing/stopping a Firestore Transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Is throwing an error a valid way to undo/stop a Firebase transaction?

For a simple example, if I was to:

- create a user profile in Firestore (not auth)
- then create that user in auth and if it fails for some reason, can I throw an error in the transaction to undo the user profile creation in my system?

Basically, my question is: does throwing an error in a Firestore transaction cause the transaction to revert Firestore documents to their previous state?

Comment: That seems like something you could easily try for yourself with some test code.  But I will say that I don't think your scheme overall is a good idea.  Transactions need to be as fast as possible and shouldn't access other blocking APIs. It's probably better to create the user account first, then use an [Cloud Functions auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) to create the document after the user account is successfully created.

Comment: Or just decorate the user profiles with the outcome of the auth.  The profile query can always ignore improperly decorated profiles.

Comment: Yeah, I was more wondering about whether it was a bad practice, as I figured there would be some way to make the transaction undo. Your answer about the transaction speed makes sense and accessing other blocking APIs.